# R two-dimensional table comes out as single column

Tags: r, crosstab, dimensions

I'm trying to make my first 2D table in R -- and it keeps coming out as a single column with the combinations of variables nested as row labels.

```
as.data.frame(table(cut(var1, breaks=seq(-1,2,by=0.1)), cut(var2, breaks=seq(-1,2,by=0.1))))
```

And the results look like

```
  Var1           Var2          Freq
1 (-1, -0.9]     (-1, -0.9]    2
2 (-0.9, -0.8]   (-1, -0.9]    0
3 (-0.8, -0.7]   (-1, -0.9]    5
4...
```

So I'm getting one column of results instead of a 2D grid, with a Var1 as a row variable but Var2 as a *column* variable.

I'm sure it's simple.

Comment: You may want to include `var1` and `var2` in your post to make this more easily reproducible.

Comment: It because `as.data.frame` converts your table to a data frame where `Var1` and `Var2` are the categories you used for making the table. Basically it converts your table from "wide" to "long" format.

Comment: If you try without `as.data.frame` do you get what you want? Try doing: `table(cut(var1, breaks=seq(-1,2,by=0.1)), cut(var2, breaks=seq(-1,2,by=0.1)))`

Comment: Dropping as.data.frame did the trick. Thanks, Jason. And everyone else. I'm picking at code from internet searches that I don't yet understand.